# How to make Gtk.ToggleToolButton behave like radiobuttons?

Tags: radio-button, gtk, vala

I am writing a Vala application and I'm using Gtk.ToggleToolButtons' in it. And I want them to behave like radiobuttons, e.g. when clicking one of the buttons, others should be set unactive. The problem is, I don't know how to do it.

I tried to do this:

```
public void uncheckButtonsExcept(string notUncheck)
{
        feedButton.active = (notUncheck == "feed");
        userButton.active = (notUncheck == "self");
        photoButton.active = (notUncheck == "photo");
        searchButton.active = (notUncheck == "search");
        newsButton.active = (notUncheck == "news");
}
```

and this function is run in each button's `clicked` callback, like this:

```
    searchButton.clicked.connect(() => {
        uncheckButtonsExcept("search");
    });
```

However when I'm clicking buttons, the program segfaults.

I tried to wrap all my function into `Idle.add()` (because I already faced problems when my program segfaults after redrawing widgets not in the main thread), like this:

```
public void uncheckButtonsExcept(string notUncheck)
{
    Idle.add(() => {
        feedButton.active = (notUncheck == "feed");
        userButton.active = (notUncheck == "self");
        photoButton.active = (notUncheck == "photo");
        searchButton.active = (notUncheck == "search");
        newsButton.active = (notUncheck == "news");
        return false;
    });
}
```

and after this my program not segfaults, but freezes.

I tried to use `set_active()`, but it also activated `toggled()` signal, which I don't want to.

So, the question: how to set button state without activating the `clicked` callback?

Comment: Why do you not want to activate the `toggle` signal?

Comment: @ace because it reacts as I clicked the button twice (when I actually clicked it and when I change the `active` state) (which is not I want to do).

Comment: Why don't you throw in some conditionals, such that the code only gets executed when it is checked? E.g. if button is checked; then uncheck other buttons; and in your uncheck function: if button is checked and notCheck != "feed"; then set_active(false); (Sorry I don't know Vala, can't give syntactically valid examples)

Comment: @ace your comment gave me the idea how to solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27548757/1206421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The `clicked` signal works only if the button's state changes, that means for my case it worked 2 times: for the button that was clicked and the button which was untoggled. That created an infinite loop like this: I have 2 buttons, I click on the first button, then the second one. The first one's `clicked` event is triggered (as its state was changed) and it is set to active. Now the second one's `clicked` event is triggered, and so on, and so on. This is not what I was looking for.

I've added a check to each of one's `clicked function like this, and now it works the way it should.

```
    feedButton.toggled.connect(() => {
        if (!feedButton.get_active())
            return;
        uncheckButtonsExcept("feed");
    });
```